# How can I add a custom attribute to an HTMLElement, that will default to an empty object on each new instance of the element?

Tags: javascript, defineproperty

If I add a new property to the prototype of `HTMLElement`, and have its default value to be '`{}`' (an empty object):

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'customObject', 
{ configurable: true, enumerable: true, writeable: true, value: {} });
```

Now I create a new `div` (which is also an `HTMLElement`):

```
var e = document.createElement('div');
```

I assign a property to the `customObject` of `e`:

```
e.customObject.prop = "bla";
```

If I alert it, I see the desired value:

```
alert(e.customObject.prop); // Displays 'bla'.
```

Now I create a new, different `div` element:

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
```

This `d` should now have an empty `customObject` property, right?

However, if I alert it:

```
alert (d.customObject.prop);
```

I get this unexpected result:

```
bla
```

How come? When I create a new element shouldn't it have a "blank" instance of HTMLElement.prototype?

( jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5pgr38mb/ )

**EDIT:**
I am looking for a solution that **will** work with deep cloning (cloneNode(true)).
Meaning - if the custom object has properties on the element ***or any of its children*** then that element or child will retain its value in the cloned instance (this is the normal behavior for "native" HTMLElement attributes).

Comment: When you use `HTMLElement.prototype` you set the property for all instance of that object (future and present), meaning all div, ul, li, input, etc tags...not only that but they would share the exact same object reference, so if you changed one of the properties of the `customObject` you would change them all

Comment: There's only one `HTMLElement.prototype`, and it only has one `customObject` property. You added the `prop` property to the one and only `HTMLElement.prototype.customObject`. Surely you don't expect each newly-created object to have its own prototype (otherwise, what would be the point of prototypes?). Or do you think that prototype values are somehow "copied" onto each instance are creation time? They are not; property access is based on a *prototype chain*. If property access fails on an instance, we try the same property access on the object's prototype.

Comment: How can I create a custom attribute that will be an empty object every time createElement is called, and will be a separate instance on that element (like all normal HTML elements attributes)?

Answer (score 3):

I might use a prototype getter that creates a new object property on the instance when called:

```
Object.defineProperty(HTMLElement.prototype, 'customObject', {
    enumerable: true,
    get: function() {
        if(this.__thisCustomObject === undefined) {
            this.__thisCustomObject = {};
            // or non-enumerable with:
            //    Object.defineProperty(this, '__thisCustomObject', {
            //        enumerable: false,
            //        value: {}
            //    };
        }
        return this.__thisCustomObject;
    },
    set: function(val) {
        this.__thisCustomObject = val;
    }
});
```

This way, any time you ask for `customObject` on an object for the first time, it creates a new object and stores it in that object's `__thisCustomObject` property. Then, all future requests for `customObject` use that element's `__thisCustomObject` property.

Note that this is getter-setter pattern very close to [how actual per-element DOM properties are implemented in the Web IDL specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381239/json-parse-not-erroring-on-cyclic-objects/20381625#20381625). The only difference here is that the per-element value is stored in a property, rather than a hidden mapping.

Comment: i didnt know setters and getters could be so easy in javascript...i like the solution a lot more than my own...my only issue is if you ever set `customObject` to be undefined (very unlikely) the getter will reset it to the default value which may not be a desireable result

Comment: @LoganMurphy If you like you could either remove the setter entirely (so you can never manually set a new object) or use a boolean `__hasSetCustomObject` property or similar. You could make that property non-editable with `configurable: false, writable: false`.

Comment: In both yours and Logan Murphy's way - `cloneNode()` will *not* clone the custom object - while "native" attributes does gets cloned correctly (e.g. `className`). I wonder if there's a way to make this work like that, without writing a new clone function. I guess one way would be to override cloneNode and reattach the custom object to the clone...)

Answer (score 2):

You could override the `document.createElement` function. Just open the console (F12 in most browsers) and click run to see the result of this code.

```js
document.createElement = (function () {
    var reference = document.createElement;
    return function (name) {
        var e = reference.call(document, name);
        e.customObject = {
            configurable: true,
            enumerable: true,
            writeable: true,
            value: {}
        };
        return e;
    };
}());

var e = document.createElement('div');
e.customObject.prop = "bla";
console.log(e.customObject.prop);
var d = document.createElement('div');
console.log(d.customObject.prop);
```

Comment: I tried your technique and @apsillers' one, and this one performs slightly faster. Thank you both.

Comment: that is due to the fact that entering and exiting the context of a function is an expensive operation in javascript...so everytime you `get` you enter and exit a function...you could avoid this by caching the `customObject` of an individual div which creates a minor inconvenience...also there is the if in the getter which is tested for every get...keep in mind the test code provided only `gets` it never `sets`