# JS Proxying HTML5 canvas context

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, ecmascript-6, es6-proxy

I'm hoping to proxy the canvas API so I can test that abstracted methods do actually draw to the canvas, however I'm hitting issues where after proxing I get an error:

`'strokeStyle' setter called on an object that does not implement interface CanvasRenderingContext2D`

This code is simplified but throws the same error:

```js
/** !NB: This snippet will probably only run in Firefox */
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 100;
canvas.height = 100;
canvas.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");                          
var calls = [];

var handler = {
    get( target, property, receiver ) {

        if ( typeof ctx[property] === 'function' ){
            return function( ...args ){
                calls.push( { call: property, args: args } )
                return ctx[property]( ...args );
            };
        }

        return ctx[property];
    }
};

try {
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    var proxy = new Proxy( ctx, handler );
    
    proxy.scale( 1, 1 );
    proxy.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    
    canvas.getContext = function(){
        return proxy;  
    };
}
catch( e ) {
    document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = 'Error: ' + e.message;   
}
```

```html
<div id="message"></div>
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix this erro by defining a `set` method on your handler:

```
set(target, property, value, receiver) {
    target[property] = value;
}
```

The reason for this error might seem a bit strange. `CanvasRenderingContext2D` instances don't have their own `strokeStyle` property. Instead, the `CanvasRenderingContext2DPrototype` (the prototype of every `CanvasRenderingContext2D` instance) has an accessor property whose `set`/`get` components will set and get the stroke-style value for the instance:

```
> ctx.hasOwnProperty("strokeStyle")
false

> Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ctx.__proto__, "strokeStyle")
Object { get: strokeStyle(), set: strokeStyle(), enumerable: true, configurable: true }
```

(If you're interested in learning more about this pattern, have a look at my answer on [JSON.parse not erroring on cyclic objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20381239/710446).)

The problem here is that the `this` supplied to the `CanvasRenderingContext2DPrototype.strokeStyle` setter is the `proxy` object, not the actual `ctx` object. That is, when we set a property on the proxy only:

```
proxy.isAFake = true;
```

and test for it in a redefined setter:

```
Object.defineProperty(ctx.__proto__, "strokeStyle", {
    set: function() {
        console.log("strokeStyle setter called for proxy?", this.isAFake);
    }
});
```

We see the setter logs the proxy-only property: `strokeStyle setter called for proxy? true`.

For whatever reason, the setter on `CanvasRenderingContext2DPrototype.strokeStyle` will accept only a genuine `CanvasRenderingContext2D` instance, not a proxied one.

Comment: Just as an added note, even after adding the setter I was running into trouble because I had a bug in my code where I was setting `ctx.strokeStyle = colour` where colour was undefined. The error I was seeing was unhelpfully referring to the proxy `TypeError: proxy set handler returned false for property '"strokeStyle"'`