# Using HTML5 canvas context as a prototype

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, prototype

I am trying to modify some functionality of the canvas context object without having to alter any code that is using this.
A solution for this by creating a `Proxy` object has been posted here: [JS Proxying HTML5 canvas context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33804653/js-proxying-html5-canvas-context).

My question is: Can this behaviour be achieved without relying on `Proxy` by using `ctx` as a prototype?

Directly using it like this

```
let acx = Object.create(ctx, {})
acx.fillStyle = 'red'
```

results in the same Error messages as mentioned in the linked question

```
TypeError: 'set fillStyle' called on an object that
    does not implement interface CanvasRenderingContext2D.
```

on all ctx methods I've tested.

In the linked question this is explained as `CanvasRenderingContext2DPrototype` not *accepting* the fake ctx object. What exactly does *accepting* mean here? Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the canvas context property descriptors, and redefine the properties/methods you want. this is a more complicated way of doing pretty much what a Proxy does.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(ctx);
var descriptors = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(prototype);

Object.defineProperties(prototype, {
    fillStyle: {
        get() {
            console.log("Getting fillStyle");
            return descriptors.fillStyle.get.call(this);
        },

        set(value) {
            console.log("Setting fillStyle to", value);
            descriptors.fillStyle.set.call(this, value);
        }
    },

    fillRect: {
        value(x, y, w, h) {
            console.log("Drawing rectangle", x, y, w, h);
            return descriptors.fillRect.value.call(this, x, y, w, h);
        }
    }
});

var canvas2 = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
ctx2.fillStyle = "red";
//>> Setting fillStyle to red
ctx2.fillRect(10, 10, 100, 100);
//>> Drawing rectangle 10 10 100 100
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```