# Why can't "hasOwnProperty" be used on instanceof HTMLInputElement?

Tags: javascript, hasownproperty

I want to check if an input element is a checkbox or text type.

I know I can do this:

```
//Type of input..
if ( input.type === "checkbox" ) 
//Contains the property..
if ( "checked" in input )
```

But my question is: why do `hasOwnProperty` returns false?

I just want to use:

```
input.hasOwnProperty("checked")
```

but it returns false everytime.

Isn't `input` an object?
I don't think so, but `typeof` said it is:

```
typeof input // returns "object"
```

So what is going on?!

Code example:

```js
const input = document.querySelector("input")
 if ( input instanceof HTMLInputElement ) {
    console.dir(input);
    console.info(typeof input);
    console.log("with 'hasOwnProperty'",input.hasOwnProperty("checked"));
    console.log("with 'in'","checked" in input);
    console.log("with 'type'",input.type === "checkbox");
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```

[The documentation about HTMLInputElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), only type checkbox have the property `checked`:

Comment: `checked` is not a member of `input` itself; it's part of `HTMLInputElement`'s prototype.

Comment: more specifically, it's a `getter` that reflects the current state of the control, rather than being a property of the particular instance of `HTMLInputElement`.

Comment: Related discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381239/json-parse-not-erroring-on-cyclic-objects/20381625#20381625 (full disclosure: my own answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"checked" in input` returns `true` because `in` evaluates all enumerable properties. On the contrary, `.hasOwnProperty()` will return `true` only if the property is a member of the object itself. It returns `false` if it's inherited or a member of the object's `prototype`.

In this case, `checked` is a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) on the `HTMLInputElement.prototype`, *not* a member of `input`.

```js
const checkbox = document.getElementById("c");
const descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'checked');

console.log("'checked' is property of input:", "checked" in checkbox);
console.log("'checked' is own-property of input:", checkbox.hasOwnProperty("checked"));
console.log("'checked' is member of prototype:", HTMLInputElement.prototype.hasOwnProperty("checked"));
console.log("'checked' is getter:", descriptor.get !== undefined);
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="c">
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tyler, Alnitak and apsillers !!